# How Can I Make multiple template for my laravel website? (I mean frontend template not laravel template engine)

Tags: php, laravel

I want define more than one template for my website and I can change it in setting page.
What should I do ?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific with that question? More than one template for what? There's [Blade documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/blade) available

Comment: There's too many ways to achieve what you want to reasonable expect anyone to provide a single good one. It mostly depends on how your page looks like currently, how familiar you are with laravel and what features your template should offer.

Comment: You should try to put your idea in code and if you have a specific coding problem you can always ask here.

Answer (score 1):

You can make more than one template like this.
Below are the two layout files in layouts folder.
**app.php** and **admin.php**
you can use these like this.

app.php

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
 //your current file code
@endsection
```

admin.php

```
@extends('layouts.admin')
@section('content')
 //your current file code
@endsection
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your codes. but it is not my solution. I know how can I extend layouts for each view. Imagine that I have an admin panel and I want create more than one template for landing page and user dashboard in other word each section can have more than one template and I can switch between them whenever I want. I can handle this with a field in my database and check it with if statement in my codes. Actually I want a logical solution for this situation. I hope I could describe what I want.